# What's wrong with my spinner ?

Tags: android

I have written this :

```
s3.getSelectedItem().toString()
```

where s3 is a spinner but the printed value is always the first item in the list?

How can I solve this?
Thanks

Comment: how are you populating your spinner, paste some code....

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com)! If you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**. I suggest reading [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read **[this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
s3.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?>arg0, View view, int arg2, long arg3) {

            String selected_val=s3.getSelectedItem().toString();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), selected_val ,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `OnItemSelected` Listener to your `spinner` and get selected item `text` from `onItemSelected()` method using `getItemAtPosition()`.

```
s3.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {

        String selected = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), selected,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    }
});
```

Hope this will help~